# Multi-Users with passport - How to get authenticated user type

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, laravel-5.8

### Problems

**Problem 1** : If the user submits an active token, the token is not identifying the user type, it always accepts regardless of middleware.

Example: `User` token can access `admin controller`

```php
Route::apiResource('admins', 'AdministratorController')->middleware('auth: admin');
```

**Problem 2**: 
Always the model obtained from the controller is the last authentication middleware placed in the route.

Example: The `user controller` based on my `api.php` get the `admin model` and if I **change the places** I will get the `user model`.

**Problem 3**: I noticed that if the token is active it fetches the middleware class type id, ie if I use a `administrator` token and the middleware is `user` it will fetch the administrator id from the table Users.

Example:

```php
/** 
 * If I set Auth:user and send a active admin token
 * I will receive the student model with the same admin id
 */
Route::get('/users', function(Request $request) {
    return auth()->guard('user')->user();
});
```

---

### Code

**Auth.php**

```php
'user' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'admins',
],
```

**Api.php**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:user', 'auth:admin']], function() {
    Route::apiResource('users', 'UserController')->only([
        'index', 'show', 'update'
    ]);
});
```

**UserController.php**

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return \Auth::user();
}
```

Comment: I've tried with [some solutions](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161#issuecomment-280892678), but still doesn't working. I found the same problem [here](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/585#issuecomment-360758770)

Comment: @techguru I put that link in the comment above yours, I tried, I was unsuccessful

Comment: Consider using [scopes](https://oauth.net/2/scope/)? That is they were designed for. If not, what's the reason for making separate providers? Auth is about to confirm if user is really the person who he's talking about but not somebody else. So I think that one provider is enough.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion, change your approach.

**Passport** uses **Token scopes** to address this situation.

**Defining Scopes**

You may define your API's scopes using the `Passport::tokensCan` method in the `boot` method of your `AuthServiceProvider`.

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

Passport::tokensCan([
    'place-orders' => 'Place orders',
    'check-status' => 'Check order status',
]);
```

**Checking Scopes**

Passport includes two middleware that may be used to verify that an incoming request is authenticated with a token that has been granted a given scope.

To get started, add the following middleware to the `$routeMiddleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
'scopes' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckScopes::class,
'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class,
```

**Check For All Scopes**

The `scopes` middleware may be assigned to a route to verify that the incoming request's access token has all of the listed scopes:

```
Route::get('/orders', function () {
    // Access token has both "check-status" and "place-orders" scopes...
})->middleware('scopes:check-status,place-orders');
```

**Check For Any Scopes**

The `scope` middleware may be assigned to a route to verify that the incoming request's access token has at least one of the listed scopes:

```
Route::get('/orders', function () {
    // Access token has either "check-status" or "place-orders" scope...
})->middleware('scope:check-status,place-orders');
```

**Complete Reference:** [Token Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#token-scopes)

Answer (score 0):

Add one more column in user's migration as 'is_admin' and then retrieve it to check whether user is an admin or normal user by `Auth::user()->is_admin`

Comment: I have 2 users ( 2 migrations; user and admin )

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no support for multiple authentication in laravel passport , but still there are some hacks which advises to change the code from Vendor folder, which is a bad practise, you can have a look at the passport issue and some solutions  from [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161) , irrespective of guards used in the application, the passport always points to users table for authentication.

Comment: I tried all the options like again and I'm still unsuccessful, don't have a way to create middleware to validate this? I'm already stuck in this for hours.

Comment: As passport is involved in this , there is no point of using middleware , its about custom guards, which are not supported in passport.

Answer (score 0):

Approach is to wrap it in a route group and include the `auth:api` and the `role:admin` middleware check on it.

In `api.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'role:admin']], function () {
    Route::apiResource('admins', 'AdministratorController')
});
```

The approach is to add another layer of protection directly to the controller within the constructor:

In your controller file:

```
    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('role:admin');
    }
```

Question:

- What roles package are you using to have the role middleware?

References:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#via-middleware
  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#controller-middleware

Answer (score -1):

```
Auth::user();
```

get retrieve all data from by auth user

Comment: I know how to get the user, I would like to know is how to get the type. User or administrator.